# How can I access a arrow functions inside another function?

Tags: javascript, constants, arrow-functions

I'm making a function to convert an array and return a string but it only works if I make a traditional function when I try to use arrow functions and run the code show me the error below:

Cannot access 'convertStringToForm' before initialization

My code:

```
const convertStringToForm = (array) => {

    var stringOfArray = ""

    for(let i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        stringOfArray += "{&quot;id&quot;:" + array[i]['id'] + ",&quot;descricao&quot;:&quot;" + array[i]['descricao'] + "&quot;}";
        if(i < (array.length - 1))
            stringOfArray += ",";
    }

    return stringOfArray;

}

function addPergunta(ev, categoria, tipo){
    let tipoConvertido = convertStringToForm(tipo);
    console.log(tipoConvertido);
}
```

Let me explain a bit what I`m doing, I have an array that comes from PHP and a send it to Javascript through a function then inside my javascript function I use a "for" to pass this information treated to my view.

I receive this array below:

```
[          
  {"id":1,"descricao":"Influente","created_at":null,"updated_at":null},
  {"id":1,"descricao":"Influente","created_at":null,"updated_at":null},
]
```

If I return this to my view, then it's not rendered, the page shows me [Object Object] [Object Object] if someone knows a better way to solve this problem I`ll be thankful. To solve the problem I create the function "convertStringToForm", this function returns a string treated like below:

```
{&quot;id&quot;:" + 2 + ",&quot;descricao&quot;:&quot;" + someText + "&quot;},
{&quot;id&quot;:" + 2 + ",&quot;descricao&quot;:&quot;" + someText + "&quot;}
```

I want to know how to use arrow functions instead of traditional functions, the code below works fine.

```
function convertStringToForm(array) {

    var stringOfArray = ""

    for(let i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        stringOfArray += "{&quot;id&quot;:" + array[i]['id'] + ",&quot;descricao&quot;:&quot;" + array[i]['descricao'] + "&quot;}";
        if(i < (array.length - 1))
            stringOfArray += ",";
    }

    return stringOfArray;

}

function addPergunta(ev, categoria, tipo){
    let tipoConvertido = convertStringToForm(tipo);
    console.log(tipoConvertido);
}
```

> I explain the question better down below.

So, I've tried to use JSON.parse() but didn't work. As @SomeshMukherjee said my point isn't the syntax, I`m justing asking why to pop that error in my screen when I try to call an arrow function inside another function.

I have this button on my page:

```
 <button onclick="addResposta(this, {{App\Tipo::all()}} )" id="btnaddResposta" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"> Text </button>
```

> {{App\Tipo::all()}} That's how a I recieve my array from PHP/Laravel.

My function creates this button when I click at this one:

```
<button type="button" onClick="return addPergunta(this, {{App\Categoria::all()}}, {{App\Tipo::all()}} )" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i> Adicionar Pergunta</button>
```

The problem is that if in my function I do something like

```
html +="<button onclick='addResposta(this," + tipo + ")' id='btnaddResposta' type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>";
```

A recieved this when I inspect my code:

```
<button onclick="addResposta(this, [Object Object] [Object Object])" id="btnaddResposta" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"> Text </button>
```

So to solve this I created a function that converts the object to the string I need, then  my button receive the correct array and be like:

```
<button onclick="addResposta(this, [{&quot;id&quot;:1,&quot;descricao&quot;:&quot;Influente&quot;,&quot;created_at&quot;:null,&quot;updated_at&quot;:null},{&quot;id&quot;:2,&quot;descricao&quot;:&quot;Conforme&quot;,&quot;created_at&quot;:null,&quot;updated_at&quot;:null},{&quot;id&quot;:3,&quot;descricao&quot;:&quot;Dominante&quot;,&quot;created_at&quot;:null,&quot;updated_at&quot;:null},{&quot;id&quot;:4,&quot;descricao&quot;:&quot;Est\u00e1vel&quot;,&quot;created_at&quot;:null,&quot;updated_at&quot;:null}] )" id="btnaddResposta" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
```

The reason why I made this question is because I want to understand better the arrow functions if I'm violating any rules of the community, please sorry for this I`m new here.

Thanks for all the answers. #peace

Comment: You're receiving a JSON string, have you tried just using `JSON.parse(yourDataFromPHP)`?

Comment: @jamiec That's not his point. He wants to use arrow functions.

Comment: @SomeshMukherjee you've heard of an XY Problem, right?

Comment: I don't see any reason why this won't work. can you make a js fiddle or provide link to the page where this is live

Comment: Personally, I don't recommend using arrow functions just for the sake of using arrow functions. Arrow functions where introduced to the language to *solve specific problems*. I generally have the following criteria: 1. The function needs to access the outer scope `this`. 2. It's a short or trivial callback (e.g. to use in Array methods) 3. The arrow function improves the readability. I don't think this function meets any... Just my 2 cents...

Answer (score 0):

> If I return this to my view, then it's not rendered, the page shows me [Object Object] [Object Object]

`[Object Object]` is just the default string representation of an object. If you want to read its properties, you just need to do so, or format them into the appropriate string.

```js
var data = [          
  {"id":1,"descricao":"Influente","created_at":null,"updated_at":null},
  {"id":1,"descricao":"Influente","created_at":null,"updated_at":null},
];

var eg1 = document.querySelector("#example1");
for(var i = 0;i<data.length;i++){
 var elem = document.createElement("div");
 elem.innerText = data[i];
 eg1.appendChild(elem);
}

var eg2 = document.querySelector("#example2");
for(var i = 0;i<data.length;i++){
 var elem = document.createElement("div");
 elem.innerText = data[i].id + ":" + data[i].descricao;
 eg1.appendChild(elem);
}
var eg3 = document.querySelector("#example3");
for(var i = 0;i<data.length;i++){
 var elem = document.createElement("div");
 elem.innerText = JSON.stringify(data[i]);
 eg1.appendChild(elem);
}
```

```html
<div id="example1"></div>
<div id="example2"></div>
<div id="example3"></div>
```

Above you can see 3 examples.

- The first just appends the array item directly, and as such the browser just interprets this as `[object Object]`.
- The second actually reads the properties of interest and builds the required string.
- The third uses `JSON.stringify` to produce a string representation of the javascript object.

Comment: So, my problem isn`t to render the info of the array in the page, but it`s to render into a parameter of a function in my button. I explain better down below.

Answer (score -4):

Try replacing:

```
const convertStringToForm = (array) => {
```

with:

```
var convertStringToForm = (array) => {
```

Comment: Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cant_access_lexical_declaration_before_init

Comment: From what I understand, the problem is actually solving ```Cannot access 'convertStringToForm' before initialization```, reason for downvotes would be nice

Comment: We can't create arrow functions using var, we can do this only using const and let. If uses var then will be poped the error:

convertStringToForm isn`t a function.

Comment: Of course we can, try in your browser console: ```var xpto = () => console.log("im a function"); xpto()```